# Inject complex objects in constructor with Unity XML configuration file

Tags: c#, xml, unity-container

I have the following classes declaration :
Logger Service,FacadeReaderService and BusinessManager. I want to inject Logger Service and FacadeReaderService in BusinessManager using Unity XML configuration.

Logger Service

```
public class LoggerService : ILoggerService
{

}
```

FacadeReaderService

```
public class FacadeReaderService : IFacadeReaderService
{
}
```

BusinessManager

```
public class BusinessManager : IBal
    {
        IFacadeReaderService _facadeReaderService;
        ILoggerService _loggerService;

        public BusinessManager(IFacadeReaderService facadeReaderService, ILoggerService loggerService)
        {
            this._facadeReaderService = facadeReaderService;
            this._loggerService = loggerService;
        }
    }
```

My question is how to inject this complex objects in my BusinessManager class ? Below is what I have done so far in my Unity Config file :

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <typeAliases>
    <typeAlias alias="IFacadeReaderService" type="Interfaces.Services.IFacadeReaderService, Interfaces" />
    <typeAlias alias="FacadeReaderService" type="Services.FacadeReader.FacadeReaderService, Services" />

    <typeAlias alias="ILoggerService" type="Interfaces.Services.ILoggerService, Interfaces" />
    <typeAlias alias="LoggerService" type="Services.Log.LoggerService, Services" />


    <typeAlias alias="IBal" type="Interfaces.Bal.IBal, Interfaces" />
    <typeAlias alias="BusinessManager" type="Bal.BusinessManager, Bal" />


  </typeAliases>
    <container>
      <register type="IFacadeReaderService" mapTo="FacadeReaderService" name="FRS"/>
      <register type="ILoggerService" mapTo="LoggerService" name="LS"/>
      <register type="IBal" mapTo="BusinessManager" name="BMS">
      <constructor>
        <param name="facadeReaderService" value="????????" />
        <param name="loggerService" value="??????" />
      </constructor>
      </register>
    </container>
</unity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found the answer to my question by looking in Microsoft documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914(v=pandp.20).aspx#config_value

I will post the unity config, just in case there is someone who will need it :

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <typeAliases>
    <typeAlias alias="IFacadeReaderService" type="Interfaces.Services.IFacadeReaderService, Interfaces" />
    <typeAlias alias="FacadeReaderService" type="Services.FacadeReader.FacadeReaderService, Services" />

    <typeAlias alias="ILoggerService" type="Interfaces.Services.ILoggerService, Interfaces" />
    <typeAlias alias="LoggerService" type="Services.Log.LoggerService, Services" />


    <typeAlias alias="IBal" type="Interfaces.Bal.IBal, Interfaces" />
    <typeAlias alias="BusinessManager" type="Bal.BusinessManager, Bal" />


  </typeAliases>
    <container>
      <register type="IFacadeReaderService" mapTo="FacadeReaderService" name="FRS"/>
      <register type="ILoggerService" mapTo="LoggerService" name="LS"/>
      <register type="IBal" mapTo="BusinessManager" name="BMS">
        <constructor>
          <param name="facadeReaderService">
            <dependency name="FRS" />
          </param>
          <param name="loggerService">
            <dependency name="LS" />
          </param>
        </constructor>
      </register>
    </container>
</unity>
```